# Should I close file descriptor passed to fchdir?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix, file-descriptor

When I want to change directory using a file descriptor, should I close the directory FD after calling `fchdir`, or the `fchdir` closes the FD automatically?

```c
int fd = open(…);
if (fd == -1) error();
fchdir(fd);
//close(fd);
```

Comment: Where did you find any hint that the file could be closed automatically?

Comment: @Gerhardh, thanks, it was typo. Or rather “think-o”.

Comment: I am not sure whether the FD is passed to the `fchdir` and it will keep using it or I can close the FD just after calling it.

Comment: I never used that thing but IMHO the rule is: You open it, you close it. If there is any function "stealing" ownership it needs to be mentioned in the spec.

Comment: Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, if the code is done with `fd` to never use it again, call `close`.

The call to `fchdir` will not close the file descriptor (see the [posix description of fchdir](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchdir.html)
).

`fchdir` likely (depends on OS and file system) obtains the needed information from `fd` before returning to the caller. Here is an example of how one specific [OS file system handles system calls for fchdir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.264/source/fs/open.c#L483)

For a more informed decision whether you should or should not close `fd` investigate the [description of `close`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html):

> The close() function shall deallocate the file descriptor indicated by fildes. To deallocate means to make the file descriptor available for return by subsequent calls to open() or other functions that allocate file descriptors. All outstanding record locks owned by the process on the file associated with the file descriptor shall be removed (that is, unlocked).